# Angular modifies properties when forEach or pure For

Tags: javascript, angularjs, for-loop, collections, foreach

Here's the **Plunker**:
https://plnkr.co/edit/itgraL2X6gCHCs7tgSZi

I have 2 collections

```
 $scope.params = [{
        id: 1,
        nombre: 'bloom'
      }, {
        id: 2,
        nombre: 'ctotal'
      }, {
        id: 3,
        nombre: 'coliformes'
}];

$scope.puntos = [{
        id: 1,
        nombre: 'votator'
      }, {
        id: 2,
        nombre: 'vw1'
      }, {
        id: 3,
        nombre: 'preparador'
      }];
```

My code in the controller looked like:

```
angular.forEach($scope.puntos, function(punto, key) {
        punto.params = $scope.params;
        angular.forEach(punto.params, function(pa, key) {
            pa.otherProp = "xxxxx";
    });
});
```

As you can see, I want to assign the params collection to each item in the puntos collection. Then I assign to the item inside the collection a value in the otherProp property.....I never change the main $scope.params....but if I output both this has changed too

Then my output is:

```
Puntos

{"id":1,"nombre":"votator","params":[{"id":1,"nombre":"bloom","otherProp":"xxxxx"},{"id":2,"nombre":"ctotal","otherProp":"xxxxx"},{"id":3,"nombre":"coliformes","otherProp":"xxxxx"}]}
{"id":2,"nombre":"vw1","params":[{"id":1,"nombre":"bloom","otherProp":"xxxxx"},{"id":2,"nombre":"ctotal","otherProp":"xxxxx"},{"id":3,"nombre":"coliformes","otherProp":"xxxxx"}]}
{"id":3,"nombre":"preparador","params":[{"id":1,"nombre":"bloom","otherProp":"xxxxx"},{"id":2,"nombre":"ctotal","otherProp":"xxxxx"},{"id":3,"nombre":"coliformes","otherProp":"xxxxx"}]}
Params

{"id":1,"nombre":"bloom","otherProp":"xxxxx"}
{"id":2,"nombre":"ctotal","otherProp":"xxxxx"}
{"id":3,"nombre":"coliformes","otherProp":"xxxxx"}
```

At first I tought that the problem was caused by using angular.forEach....So i decided to use a pure for.....the problem appears instead

```
for (var i = 0; i < $scope.puntos.length; i++) {
    var punto = $scope.puntos[i];
    punto.params = [];
    punto.params = $scope.params;
    for (var j = 0; j < punto.params.length; j++){
      var pa = punto.params[j];
      pa.otherProp = 'yyyyyy';
    }
}
```

Of course this is a simmple example...what I really want is more complex but this is stopping me...

Why is the params collection modified even If i didn't change it Manually?
Hoy to prevent it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: you are assigning same object  reference each time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing:

```
 punto.params = $scope.params;
```

you are not copying collection but create reference to it, so punto.params is the $scope.params and changing punto.params is qual to changing $scope.params. You should copy object like this:

```
 punto.params=angular.copy($scope.params);
```

Then foreach and changing punto.params will not change $scope.params.

Comment: Wow, I didn´t know It....that works! Thanks, when I'll be able I'll mark this as answered